# VBA: Split sheet on certain rule

Tags: excel, vba

I need help with VBA which will split current sheet **Test1** depending values from A rows.

**Test1** sheet is in format:

[image]

Now i need to split sheet **Test1** into two (or more) sheets which will contains all rows which begins with 1.1 and 1.4 (this values will be same rule, but different numbers).

So after run VBA code, it will be created sheet **Test1-1** (green region) containing all data which starts with 1.1:

```
1.1
1.1.1
1.1.2
1.1.3
```

And second sheet **Test1-2** (red region) which starts with 1.4:

```
1.4
1.4.1
1.4.2
```

After creation origin **Test1** sheet can be removed.

Can you please give me help or guide i don't have any clue/idea to achieve this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the below code the output will be:

Two Sheets:

1. Test1-1
2. Test1-4

If you want to get this output:

1. Test1-1
2. Test1-2

You should:

1. Sort data based on the first column
2. Create another variable with initial value 1 and every time that Sheetname change value instead of use Sheetname variable , use the new variable.

**Guidlines for:**

1. Sorting:

   ```
   Option Explicit

   Sub Sort()

       Dim LR As Long

       With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Test1")

           LR = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

       End With

   ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Test1").Sort.SortFields.Clear
   ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Test1").Sort.SortFields.Add2 Key:=Range("A1"), _
       SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
   With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Test1").Sort
       .SetRange Range("A2:D" & LR)
       .Header = xlNo
       .MatchCase = False
       .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
       .SortMethod = xlPinYin
       .Apply
   End With

   End Sub
   ```
2. New Variable

From: ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Test1-" & SheetName)

To: ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Test1-" & NewVariable)

Try:

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

    Dim LR As Long
    Dim LRN As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim SheetName As String
    Dim wsTest As Worksheet
    Dim wsNew As Worksheet

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Test1")

        LR = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    End With

    For i = LR To 1 Step -1

        With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Test1")

            SheetName = Mid(.Range("A" & i), InStr(1, .Range("A" & i).Value, ".") + 1, 1)

        End With

        Set wsTest = Nothing
        On Error Resume Next
        Set wsTest = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Test1-" & SheetName)
        On Error GoTo 0

        If wsTest Is Nothing Then
            Worksheets.Add.Name = "Test1-" & SheetName
        End If

        With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Test1-" & SheetName)

            LRN = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

        End With

        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Test1").Range("A" & i & ":D" & i).Cut ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Test1-" & SheetName).Range("A" & LRN + 1)

    Next i

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Test1").Delete
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```